# accessing tcp port inside guest os

Tags: linux, centos, networking, firewall

I would like to access a port on my guest OS from my host OS. I am using 127.0.0.1 on the guest OS since my database is also in that network, and since I just now understood(while it was right in front of me) that 192. networks and 127. networks are completely separate, I would have to use some sort of forwarding, but I don't know how exactly to do that.

```
# firewall-cmd --list-ports 
8080/tcp 80/tcp 443/tcp 8000/tcp

# nmap -p 8000 192.168.1.10 (from host OS)
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8000/tcp closed http-alt

# nmap -p 8000 localhost (from guest OS)
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8000/tcp open http-alt
```

But when I check the port using `nmap` from inside the guest OS I get state `open` while from my client machine I get state `closed`, could this be because of 192. vs 127.?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @A.B my host os is ubuntu 20.04 and guest os is centos. I have a bridged adapter and NAT configured in the virtualbox settings. I have configured things on the guest side but not on the host side, cos I did not know that was required.. what kind of settings would i need to have on the host side?

Comment: yes ping works fine, I can even access an nginx server running at port 80 using my browser in host OS but not port 8000

Comment: So there's nothing related to host/hypervisor here (deleting my comments). you should add in the question the specific commands you're using with nmap (eg: if you used 127.0.0.1 on the guest rather than its own IP etc.). Also state that it's only about 8000 and not 80. There could even be SELinux at play here

Comment: yes i realised that localhost not equal to IP address! selinux is disabled on my guest OS and since i don't have the sestatus command available also on my host OS so that could not be an issue

Answer (score 0):

While asking this question, I made a very grave mistake of not realising that the ports that I am opening are on a different network than `localhost`. So all the investigation from the host side showed me that the port was denying access because there was nothing running on `0.0.0.0:8000`, because my program was running on `localhost:8000`.

To solve this, and make the program reachable from host OS, I just had to modify the `nginx` config file that was already present on my machine, and paste the shared folder inside `/var/www/html`.

Please look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/527963/how-to-allow-nginx-in-guest-vm-access-shared-folders-in-host-os) if you want to further see how to allow nginx to use shared folders in a much more convenient way instead of copy pasting after every edit(cos who would want to do that..).